# Batch remove extra file extensions in bash

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, rename

I converted some files to another format but in doing so added an extra extension. For example `foo.bar.temp`. I wrote a script to delete the `.temp`, **but it doesn't work when the filenames have spaces**.

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" $(basename "$f" .temp) ; done
```

If I double escape `"'$f'"` then `basename` won't read the extension. If I leave it as is then it will think that the second word in the title is the directory I want to move to.

How can I just remove the `.temp`?

Comment: You need double-quotes around the `$( )`, and you're missing a `do`. Also, for bulk/automated renames like this, I always recommend using `mv -i` or `-n` to avoid overwriting files if there's a name conflict. So: `do mv -i "$f" "$(basename "$f" .temp)"`

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to type the `do`, but it's there in my script; edited to reflect that. Not sure why this is getting the `[Duplicate]` treatment when the issue is cause by iteration which the "original" doesn't mention.

Comment: I added a more direct duplicate; for more info, see the unix&linux question ["When is double-quoting necessary?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/)